# Migrating from Java 8 to java 11- not able to load jdk.internal.util class (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, java-11

Migrating from Java 8 to Java 11 open JDK. Getting weird error where one class (java.util.Arrays) from java.base module is not able to access another class called (`jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport`) from `java.base` module.

If I look at module-info of `java.base` module `jdk.internal.util` package is not exported. I tried `--add-export java.base/jdk.internal.util=ALL-UNNAMED` but getting the same error. As `--add-export` helps in exporting package to another module. Here the problem is one class from the same module is not able to access another one from the same module. Not sure what is wrong here and looking for suggestions.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.equals(Arrays.java:2873)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier.equals(ObjectIdentifier.java:345)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.parse(PKCS7.java:185)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.parse(PKCS7.java:154)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.<init>(PKCS7.java:136)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.<init>(SignatureFileVerifier.java:127)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:297)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:757)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:69)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:870)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:788)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2124)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2033)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:590)
        at com.rbccm.sales.hub.employee.tasklet.SalesHubSQLExecutionTasklet.execute(SalesHubSQLExecutionTasklet.java:45)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66)
```

Code of `SalesHubSQLExecutionTasklet` class  is as following

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.getDataSource());

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(this.getSql())) {
            if (this.getSql().toUpperCase().startsWith("UPDATE")) {
                int result = jdbcTemplate.update(this.getSql());
                LOGGER.info("{} records updated executing SQL [{}]", result, this.getSql());
            }
            else {
                jdbcTemplate.execute(this.getSql());
            }   
        }
        else if (this.sqls != null && this.sqls.length > 0) {
            int[] result = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqls);
            for (int i=0; i<sqls.length; i++) {
                LOGGER.info("SQL [{}] result [{}].", sqls[i], result[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error executing SQL [{}]", this.getSql(), ex);
    }
    LOGGER.info("Step {} execute SQL [{}] finished in {} ms.", chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepName(), this.getSql(), (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

The line no 45 is

```
int[] result = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sqls);
```

I tried to load with a separate plain class on the Unix box. And it worked fine

```
Class<?> classToLoad = Class.forName("jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport");
```

and it loaded the class successfully, so not sure what's wrong here!

Comment: Could you post your SalesHubSQLExecutionTasklet code? and your framework version (spring batch), or check [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)

Comment: Also try to load the same class in a simple command line driver.

Comment: Thanks @MatteoZanini for replying . I just added the code above

Comment: Thanks @efekctive : I tried loading the class Class.forName("jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport");  in a plain class on unix box and it worked fine . not sure why its not loading when the whole service runs :(

Comment: Then I would start trying using the utils class in other places. Like does it work in  any of the config/bean classes? These should happen before the job call

Comment: It would be good too if you could mention the versions of the libraries that you're using here. To see if they have tried fixing such instances earlier.

Comment: It seems to be an incompatible issue between your apache.commons.dbcp2 version and java 11, check [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) to see if you're using a compatible one

Comment: There is no point in playing around with the export options. Both classes are within the same module, so they do not need export options to access each other. And the error message does nowhere say that one class “is not able to access another class”, it clearly says “*could not initialize*” the class. Since the initialization works under normal circumstances, something must be altering the environment, e.g. perform code Instrumentation.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced latest dbcp Datasource with latest Hikari Datasource and it worked . Thanks all for your suggestions.