# Could not initialize class jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data

When I carefully removed part on functionality, I faced this error.
I don't change anything in area there error is thrown. JDK distrib changes can't help (and I don't migrate from 8, stay only on 11).

Part of log that I can show you:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport
    at java.util.Arrays.equals(Arrays.java:2873) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier.equals(ObjectIdentifier.java:381) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.derEncode(AlgorithmId.java:213) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.encode(AlgorithmId.java:158) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.encode(X509Key.java:471) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.buildX509Key(X509Key.java:214) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:170) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(CertificateX509Key.java:75) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:674) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1842) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:194) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:355) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:435) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1426) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1336) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421) ~[?:?]
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:40) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:94) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar:42.2.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.6.jar:42.2.6]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677) ~[java.sql:?]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189) ~[java.sql:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource.initConnection(SingleConnectionDataSource.java:224) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource.getConnection(SingleConnectionDataSource.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:465) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:475) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:508) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:515) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
```

Comment: Did you get it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033132/migrating-from-java-8-to-java-11-not-able-to-load-jdk-internal-util-class-java

Comment: That Holger's comment in ^^^ implies that the problem is most likely due to instrumentation (or similar) going wrong.  (I looked at the code for `ArraysSupport` and I concur with what he said.)  On that basis, you should be checking that your Spring dependencies have consistent version numbers and they are all compatible with Java 11.  Likewise for your application's other dependencies.  My guess is that you have picked up a version of the `javassist` JAR (or similar) that is not compatible with your JVM,